# Is putting advertisement in user profile allowed?

Tags: support, profile-page, etiquette, advertising

I just came up with the idea to put some kind of an advertisement (although I am not getting paid for it) in my profile.

***Is it allowed?***

If not, I will remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to advertise in your profile (just not anywhere else on the site).